# Using SVG as a react component with the image link as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js, jsx

I'm trying to create a react component (NextJS), which is a hexagon with an image inside it. The component should render the image that was sent as a prop. However, when I try to use multiple components with different images in the HeagonWall, all hexagons render the image of the first instance of that component instead of rendering both images accordingly. How can I solve this issue?

```
//hexagon-tile.tsx

interface HexagonTileProp {
  imageLink: string,
  imageId: string
}

export default function HexagonTile({ imageLink, imageId }: HexagonTileProp) {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg height='387' viewBox='0 0 595 687' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
        <path d='M297.5 0L594.98 171.75V515.25L297.5 687L0.0202637 515.25V171.75L297.5 0Z' fill='url(#pattern0)' />
        <defs>
          <pattern id='pattern0' patternContentUnits='objectBoundingBox' width='1' height='1'>
            <use xlinkHref={`#${imageId}`} transform='translate(-0.3) scale(0.000625)' />
          </pattern>
          <image id={imageId} width='2560' height='1600' xlinkHref={imageLink} />
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//hexagon-wall.tsx

export default function HexagonWall() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HexagonTile imageLink='https://cdn.test.com/testimg/testimg-1.jpg' imageId={crypto.randomUUID()} />
      <HexagonTile imageLink='https://cdn.test.com/testimg/testimg-2.jpg' imageId={crypto.randomUUID()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The expected outcome should have different images inside two hexagons. But this is the actual outcome:

[image]

Comment: The pattern id is still hardcoded, you can see my updated answer with a working demo

Comment: Small react note: don't put the SVG element inside a div. And either give the hexagon wall div a class, or use a more semantically appropriate element, but don't use bare divs - it makes page inspection near impossible, don't shoot yourself in the foot. Also remember that `id` attributes are _unique_ identifiers: it doesn't matter how many different elements with the same `id` attribute you have: everything will only ever find the same thing, given an `id`. So instead of using the same `id` in each SVG component, generate a _different_ `id` each time you create a HexagonTile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either be auto generating the image and pattern ids, or passing id in as a prop. You have hardcoded them for every image / pattern, so every svg will just take the first image / pattern with that id in the DOM.

You can use `crypto.randomUUID()` to generate a unique id.

Note support for this function: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_crypto_randomuuid

Note [`xlink:href` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) you can just use `href`.

```
export default function HexagonTile({ imageLink }: HexagonTileProp) {
  const id = crypto.randomUUID();
  const imageId = 'image' + id;
  const useHref = '#' + imageId;
  const patternId = 'pattern' + id;
  const pathFill = 'url(#' + patternId + ')';
  return (
    <div>
      <svg
        height="387"
        viewBox="0 0 595 687"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <path
          d="M297.5 0L594.98 171.75V515.25L297.5 687L0.0202637 515.25V171.75L297.5 0Z"
          fill={pathFill}
        />
        <defs>
          <pattern
            id={patternId}
            patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
            width="1"
            height="1"
          >
            <use href={useHref} transform="translate(-0.3) scale(0.000625)" />
          </pattern>
          <image id={imageId} width="2560" height="1600" href={imageLink} />
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vq1t45?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: I've created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-shape-wf42jm?file=/src/Hexagon.tsx) and it does not look like the `id` is the issue

Comment: @RubenSmn the `id` is the issue, I just missed there was a hardcoded pattern id as well.

Comment: Note that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76794097/using-svg-as-a-react-component-with-the-image-link-as-a-prop#comment135383983_76794256) also applies here: SVG inside HTML5 is _not_ "an SVG document" with namespaces and xlinks, it's an HTML SVG _element_ that follows the rules of HTML elements. No namespaces, no xlink.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a duplicate pattern id.

Fix it by using your `id` props :

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 595 687">
  <path
    d="M297.5 0L594.98 171.75V515.25L297.5 687L0.0202637 515.25V171.75L297.5 0Z"
    fill={`url(#pattern${id})`}
  />
  <defs>
    <pattern
      id={`pattern${id}`}
      patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      width="1"
      height="1"
    >
      <use
        href={`#${id}`}
        transform="translate(-0.3) scale(0.000625)"
      />
      <image id={id} width="2560" height="1600" href={imageLink} />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Modern HTML (even if effected through React) note: when used inside an HTML5 document, SVG does not use namespaces. It is fully constrained by what it's allowed to do when inside an HTML5 document. Because of that, there's also no `xlink` anything. The href attribute is just `href`. And on a JS note, of course, string concatenation got replaced with the much safer, and much saner, templating string.